# I don't know how to do the code for an rtc controlling a relay

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, rtc

I'm doing a project for my brother witch is an automatic watering thing,
it's all working fine but I just don't know how to repeat the code to make the relay say come on for 5min at 0900 than 5min at 1200 and also 5min at 1700.
how do I do this, I'm not very good at this so I need clear instructions or someone to write it.
pls help.
thank you, James.

here is the code I need to be repeated to meet what I need done, basically I just need the relay to trigger every 4h for 5min. its on an rtc on an Arduino UNO.

```
#include <DS3231.h>

int Relay = 4;

DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
Time t;

const int OnHour = 19; //SET TIME TO ON RELAY (24 HOUR FORMAT)
const int OnMin = 55;
const int OffHour = 19; //SET TIME TO OFF RELAY
const int OffMin = 56;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  rtc.begin();
  pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  t = rtc.getTime();
  Serial.print(t.hour);
  Serial.print(" hour(s), ");
  Serial.print(t.min);
  Serial.print(" minute(s)");
  Serial.println(" ");
  delay (1000);

  if(t.hour == OnHour && t.min == OnMin){
    digitalWrite(Relay,HIGH);
    Serial.println("LIGHT ON");
    }

    else if(t.hour == OffHour && t.min == OffMin){
      digitalWrite(Relay,LOW);
      Serial.println("LIGHT OFF");
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you simply add two more `if` blocks?

Comment: no matching function for call to 'DS3231::DS3231(const uint8_t&, const uint8_t&)
please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most likely find nobody here, who will write the code for you, since this is not a free code writing service. But I will suggest a good way.

> I just need the relay to trigger every 4h for 5min

The phrase "every x hours" screams for using the modulo operator `%`. Modulo gives you the rest value of an integer division. See these values:

```
0 % 4 = 0
1 % 4 = 1
2 % 4 = 2
3 % 4 = 3
4 % 4 = 0
5 % 4 = 1
...
7 % 4 = 3
8 % 4 = 0
```

You see, the modulo 4 operation gives you zero every 4 hours starting with midnight. So make an if statement based on that

```
if(hour % 4 == 0 && min == 0)
```

to switch on and

```
if(hour % 4 == 0 && min == 5)
```

to switch off. Just change your code in this way and you are done.

Comment: Thankyou, I will give it a try tomorrow and see how it goes  then let you know.

Comment: Also were do I put all the 0%4 things?

Comment: In your code you already have if statements for turning the relay on and off. And I included corresponding if statements using the modulo operator in my answer. These if statements can be used to turn the relay on and off. It is your part, to write that in your code. If something in my answer is not clear, please specify what, so that I can better explain how this works.

Comment: I understand were the statements go but I have no idea were to put the list of values, as I sayed I'm pretty dumb when it comes to this so I'm sorry if I'm being a bit stubborn. I'm young and don't have a lot of knowledge on how to write this. Your hell so far is very much appreciated.

Comment: The list of values doesn't belong in your code. I've just included it to show  how the modulo operator works

Comment: 'hour' was not declared in this scope

Comment: As I said, I will not write the code for you. You have to take the if statements from my answer and change them for your case. Try to understand your old code. Then try to understand, what the principle is, that I described. Then you should be able to change your code accordingly. But you need to learn and understand. You can also do some basic tutorials with your Arduino to learn the absolute basics. And learning C is also good.